# Draw graph with edge widths proportional to their weights

Tags: python, networkx

I have a system where each node has a relation with all the other nodes but the weights are different. 
For example A -> B with a weight of 0.5 and B -> A with a weight of 2. 
The following example draws a directed graph but there is no visual differentiation between the edges.

I would like to have lines with different widths depending on the corresponding edges weights.

```
from itertools import combinations
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(15.0, 10.0))   
node_names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] # Get a list of only the node names  
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(node_names)
for var in combinations(node_names,2):
    G.add_edge(var[0], var[1], weight = np.random.uniform(0, 4))
    G.add_edge(var[1], var[0], weight = np.random.uniform(0, 4)) 


e = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in G.edges(data=True)]

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)  # positions for all nodes

# nodes
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=200)

# edges
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=e,width=2)

# labels
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=20, font_family='sans-serif')
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, try this to make sure you have a problem:

```py
from itertools import combinations
import random
import networkx as nx

random.seed(0)

node_names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(node_names)

for (u, v) in combinations(node_names, 2):
    G.add_edge(u, v, weight = random.uniform(0, 4))
    G.add_edge(v, u, weight = random.uniform(0, 4))

for (u, v, weight) in G.edges.data('weight'):
    print(f"Edge {u} -> {v} weights {weight}.")
```

In which you should for example see that `A -> B` is different from `B -> A`:

```
Edge A -> B weights 3.3776874061001925.
Edge A -> C weights 1.68228632332338.
Edge A -> D weights 2.045098885474434.
Edge B -> A weights 3.03181761176121.
```

As far as representation goes if you need to match arcs width with their weights, you can use `draw`'s `width` option. You will also need to use an `arc` representation for your graph so arcs don't overlap :

```py
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
edge_widths = [w for (*edge, w) in G.edges.data('weight')]
nx.draw(G, pos, width=edge_widths, connectionstyle='arc3, rad=.15')
```

Comment: My question was not clear (thx for add the import itertools btw). My network is well defined but I would like to make a graph of it. When I graph it I have a only one line with two arrow. I would like two lines with different size depending on the weight.

Comment: Ahh, I see, you are mistaking drawn edges width with edges weights. In graph theory, when we talk about weights, it's always some value attached to the edge and has nothing to do with graphic representation of the graph. For example, in a road network, the weight might be something like the length of the road segment connecting two intersections (here segments are edges, intersections  are nodes and weights are distances). I will edit my answer to add some details, but this question (and title) should also be edited to reflect your (actual) question better.